# Port and existing VS 2013 ASP.Net project to VNext on linux

Tags: asp.net, mono, asp.net-core

I have an existing Visual Studio 2013 ASP.Net MVC project that I would like to get running on Linux using Mono and VNext. I have mono and VNext all up a running on Linux but I can't work out if there are any easy ways to get my existing project up and running. I have search the next and seen various examples of how to build a new project but nothing about converting/migrating and existing project.

Does anyone have any hints tips etc. Do I have to manually convert the various .csproj files to json files or is there a better way.

I have the sample app from the github up and running.

Comment: I don't think any porting tools are out yet. I'm doing the same thing, not to linux, but vnext. The DB was the first aspect I tackled. Does your app use a DB? I was using the simple membership provider, but still it's a pain to override the password hashing algorithm in vnext.

Comment: No database at the moment, I am just trying to figure out if there is a nice easy way to migrate the .csproj files to json etc.